# Null Pointer exception when extending ActionbarActivity Class

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, expandablelistview, android-actionbaractivity

I am developing an expandable list view application on which i want to add action bar.

It seems for action bar visibility I need to extend ActionBarActivity Class, but to run my Expandable list activity I should extend activity class.

So, I changed following code

from

> `public class Time extends Activity {`

to

> `public class Time extends ActionBarActivity {`

assuming following hierarchy

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
                   ↳    android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
                       ↳    android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
```

But,when i run my application now i get null pointer exception at    `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Please check log here:

```
12-19 00:10:48.995  14128-14128/sudharshanapps.clock E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sudharshanapps.clock, PID: 14128
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sudharshanapps.clock/sudharshanapps.clock.Time}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at sudharshanapps.clock.Time.onCreate(Time.java:247)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could you please suggest, what is missing here or any references or ideas where to look for.

Answer (score 2):

Changed Manifest file from

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="Time across Globe"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

to

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="Time across Globe"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
```

It solved the issue